# Postfix relay to one server from multiple users

Tags: osx, email, postfix, forwarding

I am trying to build a smart host in an Unix system, with Server app, Mail service and an Open Directory for local users.

My question is if there is a way to use an email just for forwarding mail from several different mail users, i have test this just for one user email account, in both forwarding and in Mail app and works well, but i tried to add a second account and i receive a message telling that there already was an account for that domain (something like that i dont remember well). In exchange from microsoft i have saw one config there that there was an account just for forwarding mail, and in the ISP mail server, that was a normal email account, but locally in the exchange, i could access it like a regular local email account.

Is it possible to do or there is some workarounds for this with this app's or in background messing with Postfix?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found in postfix documentation a solution for this issue, through this it is possible to relay mails from multiple local accounts to multiple external accounts in different domains, in other words relay host will be ignored(/left as backup i believe) with this:

http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#client_sasl_sender